# How to access methods between components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an application with two sibling components:

[image]

I would like, upon a specific action in `Component1` to trigger a method in `Component2`. **Is there a way to do this directly?**

Currently, I use an over-engineered solution:

- upon the specific change in `Component1`, it `$emit` a signal to the parent
- ... who, through a handler, modifies a flag in its `data`
- ... which is passed as `prop` to `Component2`
- ... which `watch` this `prop` and triggers the appropriate method upon chnage.

This composition of flags, handlers and watchers is too complex so i am hoping for a more direct solution.

Comment: Have you thought of global event bus. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication

Comment: How about keeping the method in insolated object (store), so you can access that method from everywhere ?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna: that would be a great solution but how will `bus` (to take the example in the docs) be visible in the components? (in other words, how to call it, because a bare `bus` in `undefined`). I add my components with `Vue.component()` so I do not see how to make it aware of `bus`

Comment: @WoJ you can setup an event listener in the created lifecycle hook and can make changes in the callback.....`bus.$on('event-name', () => { //...callback });` and even stop listening to events in destroyed hook by `bus.$off('event-name");`

Comment: @VamsiKrishna: thanks a lot. I figured out the same thing this night and I am implementing right now.

Comment: @WoJ i had to go out yesterday ... so could not reply immediately...if any further doubt reply me...:)

Comment: @VamsiKrishna: it works perfectly now, thank you again for the idea

Comment: @WoJ happy you worked it out :)